# How can I remove/delete bounding boxes while detecting objects?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm using TensorFlow for my object detection task but sometimes it shows false positives.So I want to filter some bounding boxes.
For example if object's bounding box's width is smaller than the 50% of whole screen, show the box:

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
            # W = width of frame, H = height of frame
            ymin = int((boxes[0][0][0] * H))
            xmin = int((boxes[0][0][1] * W))
            ymax = int((boxes[0][0][2] * H))
            xmax = int((boxes[0][0][3] * W))

            if (xmax -xmin) < W*0.5:
                vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    frame,
                    np.squeeze(boxes),
                    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                    np.squeeze(scores),
                    category_index,
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    line_thickness=1,
                    )
```

However, it doesn't work. It still shows all the bounding boxes. I tried to compare areas of whole screen area and it didn't work either.

[Image from false cow detection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJOuK.png)

**In short how can I remove the outer and bigger box with post or pre-processing?**

I'd be very glad if anyone can help.

EDIT:
My model is SSD Mobilenet v2. I trained with my own dataset which includes just one class (cow) and as an input data, I'm streaming a video through OpenCV.

Comment: `boxes` is an array containing multiple detections, but you are just checking the size of the first one with your indexing. You probably should try to understand how the outputs of your model are defined. If you want more specific help you need to describe your model, its input and outputs in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right. It's SSD MobileNet model. I trained with my own dataset. It has just one class which is cows. As an input I'm giving a video from OpenCV and in the end I'm trying to detect and track the object. Actually more I want to do is remove the information about those big boxes from my arrays (boxes, scores, classes etc) but I don't know how are they indexing actually and I couldn't find any documentation about it.